# Django error{ Page not found, error 404},

Tags: python, django

[directory [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2M2KE.png)] [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1bEc.png) Getting this error when trying to connect

```
Using the URLconf defined in project.urls, Django tried 
these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
 The current path, polls/, didn't match any of these.
```

C:\Users\Kwaku Biney\Desktop\dj\mysite\polls\urls.py

```
 from django.urls import path
  from . import views
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.index, name='index'),]
```

C:\Users\Kwaku Biney\Desktop\dj\mysite\mysite\urls.py

```
 from django.contrib import admin
 from django.urls import include, path

 urlpatterns = [
path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),]
```

mysite\polls\views.py

```
 from django.shortcuts import render
 from django.http import HttpResponse
 def index(request):
return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the polls index.")
```

settings.py

```
 # Application definition

 # Application definition

  INSTALLED APPS= [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'polls',]
```

polls/apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
class PollsConfig(AppConfig):
   name = 'polls'
```

Comment: In the settings what is in `ROOT_URLCONF` ?

Comment: ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

Comment: Can you add polls/apps.py ?

Comment: @BriseBalloches added it now

Comment: @KwakuE.Biney can you once add the screenshot of the error instead of error itself

Comment: @SAISANTOSHCHIRAG https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1bEc.png  , in the post too

Comment: Add `app_name = "polls"` to your polls/urls.py file. before urlpatterns

Comment: @OsmanDurdag Same error, :(

Comment: @KwakuE.Biney I created a project and wrote the same code as yours. It's working for me.

Comment: @SAISANTOSHCHIRAG is there anything I might be doing wrong? Apart from code... do I have to run the code or something after the edits?

Comment: @KwakuE.Biney Try restarting the server. Sometimes it won't restart automatically after changes

Comment: @KwakuE.Biney Stop the present running server and then type the command `python manage.py runserver`

Comment: Is it possible that your are running server in a wrong directory maybe in an other django project?

Comment: Yeah . Maybe you are running a different project with the same name.

Comment: @KevRob included directory image in post. check out for me

Comment: @SAISANTOSHCHIRAG  included directory image in post. check out for me

Comment: @KwakuE.Biney I use VSCode and it seems like you have not saved the files. Once save all the files and try restarting the server.  In VSCode you can see if the file is saved or not, beside the file name on top in place of close button

Comment: @KwakuE.Biney In PyCharm you need not save the files manually, but in VSCode you should.

Comment: @SAISANTOSHCHIRAG i hit save but i don’t see any changes on file name. Also, how do I kill the server? What is CTRL BREAK?

Comment: Did you save all files, try CTRL + K + S in VSCode on windows. When you see the grey point after your file name, it means that you didn't save.

Comment: @KevRob I think the problem was that I hadn't saved the files. When i run it now, I see the text, https://imgur.com/zkHaKJe , but when i run http://127.0.0.1:8000/ , I don't see Django's server. Is that normal? All I see is https://imgur.com/L4Pzvtt

Comment: @KwakuE.Biney Your project is working fine now. Since you returned HTTPResponse, you see only the text. Now, in this link https://imgur.com/L4Pzvtt , there is not view for the URL 127.0.0.1:8000. Therefore, you get page not found error.

Answer (score 0):

mysqite/mysite/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('polls/',include('polls.urls'))
]
```

mysite/polls/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path,include
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
]
```

mysite/polls/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from django.http import HttpResponse
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the polls index.")
```

After running the server[image]

Answer (score 0):

Problem was I hadn't saved the files. Did that by CTRL + K + S in VSCode on windows. [page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqsbc.png)

You can turn on AutoSave on VsCode also by File => Autosave on Menu Bar.